# How do I check in python if my Cloudant or couchDB connection still exists

Tags: python, connection, cloudant

I would like to check in my python program if I still have a connection to the cloudantDB or couchDB. I can not find a parameter in the cloudant python library to check for.

Here is how to connect and disconnect, but in the lib I can not find something like .isConnected()
http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: You might use the `with` notation as shown in the [docs](http://python-cloudant.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cloudant.html#cloudant.cloudant) since this opens and closes the connection automatically.

Comment: Hi albert, thanks for the update. It's a great idea but as connecting to the database takes 2 secs for me I would like to keep the DB connected and just check every time if the connection still exists and then reconnect. (IP address change aso.)